# Переключение между картинками c помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как добиться переключения между 4 картинками, так чтобы при клике на одну из них  менялась главная картинка?

*P.S. у меня там несколько таких галерей, и при клике на одну картинку меняются сразу все. Попробовал с помощью this или next, не получилось. Что можно придумать, чтобы предотврaтить это?*

```js
$('.img_list img').on('click', function(e){
    $('.main_img img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

```css
.img_list{
  display:flex;
}
.main_img img{
    width:60%;

}
.img_list img{
  width:20%;
  align-self:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_img">
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
</div>

<div class="img_list">
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/670332049522298880/N5uJZueS_400x400.jpg">
  <img src="http://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg">
  <img src="http://myhswm.org/images/sized/images/animals/LRM_EXPORT_20171221_154654-256x256.jpg">
</div>
<div class="main_img" style="margin-top:3rem">
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
</div>

<div class="img_list">
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/670332049522298880/N5uJZueS_400x400.jpg">
  <img src="http://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg">
  <img src="http://myhswm.org/images/sized/images/animals/LRM_EXPORT_20171221_154654-256x256.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
$(".img_list img").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".img_list").prev(".main_img").find("img").
    attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

```css
.img_list {
  display: flex;
}

.main_img img {
  width: 60%;
}

.img_list img {
  width: 20%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_img">
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
</div>

<div class="img_list">
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/670332049522298880/N5uJZueS_400x400.jpg">
  <img src="http://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg">
  <img src="http://myhswm.org/images/sized/images/animals/LRM_EXPORT_20171221_154654-256x256.jpg">
</div>

<div class="main_img">
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
</div>

<div class="img_list">
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/670332049522298880/N5uJZueS_400x400.jpg">
  <img src="http://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg">
  <img src="http://myhswm.org/images/sized/images/animals/LRM_EXPORT_20171221_154654-256x256.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: у меня там несколько таких галерей и при клике на одну картинку меняются сразу все. Попробовал с помощью this или next, не получилось. Что можно придумать чтобы предотвратить это?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Отлично сработало

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.img_list img').on('click', function(e){
    $('.main_img img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: немного опоздал)

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('.img_list img').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).parents('.gallery').find('.main_img img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

```css
.img_list{
  display:flex;
}
.main_img img{
    width:60%;

}
.img_list img{
  width:20%;
  align-self:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
 <div class="main_img">
   <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
 </div>
 <div class="img_list">
   <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
   <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/670332049522298880/N5uJZueS_400x400.jpg">
   <img src="http://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg">
   <img src="http://myhswm.org/images/sized/images/animals/LRM_EXPORT_20171221_154654-256x256.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
 <div class="main_img" style="margin-top:3rem">
   <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
 </div>
 <div class="img_list">
   <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/956ba2_af20317893ce438187fccc708d37db44~mv2_d_2268_2268_s_2.jpg_256">
   <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/670332049522298880/N5uJZueS_400x400.jpg">
   <img src="http://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg">
   <img src="http://myhswm.org/images/sized/images/animals/LRM_EXPORT_20171221_154654-256x256.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
```